# jquery function calculation no working right on second call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a subtotals function that does some calculations on an html table (sums up columns that have assigned classes). I have modified it so that I can pass arguments to it, and on the first function call it works as desired. When I call it again it creates the cell and assigns the class, but the math or apparently something else is wrong because it is returning NaN. Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khemikal/r5xm9act/159/) and below is my function. Any help would be appreciated!

```
//v is parent,z is child element,w is which child column....ex: 0 or 1, y is first run or not, z is class name you want assigned
function subtotals(v, w, x, y, z) {
    $(v).each(function (index, element) {
        var subTotalAmt = 0;
        var numRows = parseInt($(this).attr("rowspan"));
        var firstRow = $(this).parent();
        var lastRow = firstRow.nextAll('tr').slice(numRows - 2, numRows - 1);
        var currentRow = firstRow;
        for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            subTotalAmt += parseInt($(currentRow.children(w)[x]).text());
            currentRow = currentRow.next("tr");
        }
        if(y == 'yes'){
        lastRow.after('<tr><td class="sub0">Sub Total</td><td class="' + z + '">' + subTotalAmt + '</td></tr>');
        $(this).attr('rowspan', numRows + 1);
        }
        else {
        lastRow.append('<td class="' + z + '">' + subTotalAmt + '</td>');
        }        
    });
}
$(function doSubtotals() {
  subtotals('.parent','.child','1','yes','sub1');
  subtotals('.parent','.child','2','no','sub2');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your `<td>` are not containing a valid number , which case the calculation to fail and put `NaN` (stands for 'Not a Number') instead of a valid number `(NaN + number = NaN)`.
To fix this i added this condition to your code :

```
  for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        var tdValue=0;
        if(!isNaN(parseInt($(currentRow.children(w)[x]).text())))
        {
            tdValue=parseInt($(currentRow.children(w)[x]).text());
        }
        subTotalAmt += tdValue;
        currentRow = currentRow.next("tr");
    }
```